# Indefinite integral of $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

For this I tried using the substitution technique, but it got me nowhere near the right answer.

What my notepad looks like:
$$f(x) = \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}+1}$$
and
$$F(x) = \int f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{x} &= t \\
dx &= 2t\cdot dt
\end{cases}
= \int\frac{t}{t+1}\cdot2t\cdot dt = \boxed{\dfrac{4t(t+1)-2t^2}{(t+1)^2}+c}$$

After swapping $t$ with $x$ again the answer is not even close; where did I go wrong?

#### Also as a follow up question:

- How do I know when the proper situation is to use **integration by substitution** above **integration by parts**?

Comment: Why not to choose $\sqrt x+1=t$ ? It will be simpler, I suppose.

Comment: You're right, still new to this. I'll return when I've tried this.

Comment: To the follow-up question: it is often said that differentiation is a craft, integration is an art. Experience and trial and error is the only general rule there is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to the first question, the basic expression inside the OP's boxed formula, $4t(t+1)-2t^2\over(t+1)^2$, is the *derivative* of $2t^2\over t+1$, not its *integral*.

As for the second question, there's no hard and fast rule (at least none that I know of), but in this case using a **substitution** to get rid of the square root signs was a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Try instead substituting $t=\sqrt{x}+1$. Then $x=(t-1)^2$, and $\mathrm{d}x=2(t-1)\,\mathrm{d}t$, and hence:

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}+1}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int\frac{t-1}{t}\cdot2(t-1)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=2\int\frac{(t-1)^2}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt x + 1 = t \implies \sqrt x = t-1$$ $$dx =2(t-1)\,dt, \quad \sqrt x = t-1$$

$$\int \frac{2(t-1)^2}t\,dt $$

Answer (score 1):

First:

$$\left(\frac{2t^2+4t}{(t+1)^2}\right)'=\frac{4(t+1)^2-4t(t+2)}{(t+1)^3}=\frac4{(t+1)^3}$$

and this doesn't look like the function you were trying to integrate: $\;\frac{2t^2}{t+1}\;$ !

Your function in the integral is :

$$\frac{2t^2}{t+1}=2t-\frac{2t}{t+1}=2t-2+\frac2{t+1}$$

and thus the integral in fact is

$$\int\left(2t-2+\frac2{t+1}\right)dt=t^2-2t+2\log|t+1|+C$$

and taking back the original variable according to your substitution:

$$t=\sqrt x\implies \int\frac{\sqrt x}{1+\sqrt x}dx=x-2\sqrt x+2\log(\sqrt x+1)+C$$

Comment: The expression you wind up integrating should start with a $2t$, not $2t^2$.

Comment: I have a question, when I did your last step I got a constant term $1-4 = -3$. Why is that not in your step? Or do you remove it because it's already in the definition of $C$?

Comment: @XMLParsing First, yes: any constant is possible to include it in the general constant $\;C\;$ . Second, how did you get that $\;-3\;$ there?